# Azure ML Studio Error 0035: Features for The vocabulary is empty

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am attempting to give classifications to various bodies of text using Azure ML Studio and I have my successful output all the way until I deploy and test a web service. Once I deploy my web service and attempt to test it I get the following error:

Error 0035: Features for The vocabulary is empty. Please check the Minimum n-gram document frequency. required but not provided., Error code: ModuleExecutionError, Http status code: 400

The vocabularies for the extract n-gram modules are not empty. The only aspect that changes from the working model to the Web service error is the web service input.

[Training Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBsDS.png)
[Predictive Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Sq1.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 N-GRAMS modules in your "Training experiment" as shown on the screenshot of the link below

`Follow the steps from the link:`

- COPY your NGRAMS module,
- SET one in "CREATE" (for training) and the other one in "READ" (for testing)
- CONNECT the vocabulary output from the training NGRAMS to the input vocabulary of the testing NGRAMS
- SAVE the output vocabulary from testing part to a "Convert to Dataset" block.
- You can then use this to feed your deployments NGRAMS steps in "READ" mode.

`See steps here =>`

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/machine-learning/algorithm-module-reference/extract-n-gram-features-from-text

Answer (score 0):

The MS documentation is misleading here.

What Azure ML Studio is looking for is a second input for the "extract n-grams" pill in the predictive experiment.

[image: Where to add second input]

The desired second input is a dataset. The one you want is produced by the "extract n-grams" pill in the training experiment. To get and use this dataset, go to your training experiment and add a "Convert to CSV" pill on the second output node of the "Extract N-Grams" pill. Then save this as a dataset.

Now you use it as a second input in your predictive model's "n-grams" pill. You should be good to go!

Comment: Can you supply a full pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

***From the Azure GitHub***: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/algorithm-module-reference/extract-n-gram-features-from-text.md

**Score or publish a model that uses n-grams**

1. Copy the Extract N-Gram Features from Text module from the training dataflow to the scoring dataflow.
2. Connect the Result Vocabulary output from the training dataflow to
   Input Vocabulary on the scoring dataflow.
3. In the scoring workflow, modify the Extract N-Gram Features from
   Text module and set the Vocabulary mode parameter to ReadOnly. Leave
   all else the same.
4. To publish the pipeline, save Result Vocabulary as a dataset.
5. Connect the saved dataset to the Extract N-Gram Features from Text
   module in your scoring graph.